# Good Resources for Teradata & Business Objects?

Tags: sql, database, resources, business-objects, teradata

Can any one suggest good resources and practice exercises for Teradata and Business Objects and their combination. I have no idea on where to start..

I am aware of SQL, database concepts and programming languages like c, php, c++, C#. I need to learn teradata, BO practically. I need to develop applications for reporting data from Teradata on a website using Business objects. Any suggestions, links, books are welcome. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on getting a strongly typed dataset working with teradata currently, and not having a lot of luck, here are some resources that might assist you:

[TeraData Forums](http://www.teradataforum.com/)

[TERADATA ADVISORY GROUP SETS BEST PRACTICES FOR BUSINESS OBJECTS AND TERADATA CUSTOMERS](http://www.businessobjects.com/pdf/partners/teradata_advisory_group.pdf)

[Best Practices for Teradata Deployments](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12104_01/books/AnyInstAdm/AnyInstAdmPreInstall12.html)

[Teradata Developer Exchange](http://developer.teradata.com/)

Comment: Oh thank you. After very long time some body replied to some teradata question. I will look into your links Thank you.

Comment: teradata support seems sparse everywhere I go. No luck today on trying to let vs2008 build me a nice strongly typed dataset against teradata using the ole .net provider for teradata.

Answer (score 0):

The BOB forum seems to be the only site on the Internet that consistently shows up when searching for Business Objects help.  I find it useful to do Google searches with Site:http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj in the search string.  I've never been able to find anything on the forum without searching via Google.

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/index.php

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into this.